# Can I use an install4j launcher to restart a java application?

Tags: install4j

I need to restart a java GUI application in response to a user action, in a similar way to eclipse restarting itself when you switch workspaces.

We currently use an install4j launcher, so I'm wondering if the launcher can be configured to stay running and to restart the application if I exit the application with a particular return code or something like that?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a feature in install4j. However, you can just start the launcher again by using java.lang.ProcessBuilder and call System.exit().

If the launcher is a single instance GUI launcher, you have to use another executable that waits for the launcher to shut down and then restarts the original executable. This can be done easily with a custom installer application that contains an "Execute launcher" action in its "Startup" node. The custom installer application is launched via the API with the arguments

```
-q -wait 20
```

i.e. it is executed in unattended mode (no GUI) and waits for a maximum of 20 seconds for all installed launchers to shut down. To show a progress bar, add

```
-splash "Restarting application"
```

to the arguments. The code to launch the custom installer application looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.install4j.api.launcher.ApplicationLauncher;

try {
    ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("ID", new String[] {
       "-q","-wait","20"
    }, false, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //TODO handle invocation failure
}
```

where ID has to be replaced with the ID of the custom installer application.

Comment: Hi, does it also work for single instance windows GUI application ??

Comment: No, in that case it is more complicated, please see my updated answer.

Comment: As of today the `-wait` option seems to have been dropped. How could this be achieved today? Moreover, how can i pass command line arguments to the launcher?

Comment: The `-wait` option has not been dropped. What problem do you experience? Note that this option is only available for installer applications, not for generated launchers.

Comment: I tried to run the restarter.exe from the command line with the `-wait` option... So this is not possible? The `-wait` option only works when supplied to the api call? (Which would be perfectly fine for me)

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the API, you can pass it on the command line as well as long as restarter.exe is an installer application.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out somehow. I'm now using an installer application with a "shut down calling launcher" and an "execute launcher" action. However, is it possible to pass through command line arguments to the executed launcher?

Comment: Figured that one out on my own. I'm using installer variables passed into the installer with `-VmyVar=test` and then passing those to the launcher in the _execute launcher_ action

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to configure the executable name.

Otherwise it will just fail silently: The installer compilation and the `launchApplication()` call will not throw any errors. And without any error messages or log files to look at, this took me a day of trial & error to figure out.

[image]

Also, it is possible to set a custom ID to avoid cryptic application IDs:

```
      ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("restarter", new String[] { "-q", "-wait", "20", "-splash", "Restarting..." }, /* blocking */ false, /* callback */ null);
```

[image]