# Stop launcher when uninstalling in install4j

Tags: install4j

In install4j how can I close a launcher before uninstallation? The launcher is configured to run only a single instance.

I found this : [Can I use an install4j launcher to restart a java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981152/can-i-use-an-install4j-launcher-to-restart-a-java-application) but I'm unsure how to implement the shutdown in the installer.

Any help appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "Check for running processes" action for that purpose.